# Race between answers and/or comments

Tags: discussion, answers

Sorry if it’s been asked before, if yes, can someone please point me to the right reference?

It frequently happens to me that I am either answering a question or commenting on it, only to realise that someone else gave essentially the same answer (sometimes as a comment when mine was an answer, or vice versa) a few seconds faster. (I am not exactly the faster typist.)

What is the right etiquette here?

- Do nothing, my post may be based on the same idea but may be clearer, better presented etc. so it is only fair that it competes with the existing one.
- Delete my post, implicitly acknowledging the priority.
- Leave my post but edit it to give some credit to the person who came up with their post first.
- Something else (e.g. upvote the other person’s work; I think I would do that anyways...)

Comment: I'd say go for the first bulleted option, for relatively closely posted answers  That happens, and while the ideas may be the same, they're likely expressed differently.